# Erlang tail recursion for finding the number of elements in each list of the input list

Tags: erlang

How may I use tail recursion in Erlang to say I have lists [[1], [2], [3], [3,2]] and I'd like to output the list [[1], [1], [1], [2]] where each list in the output list represents the number of element(s) for each list in the input list?

I am a beginner in functional programming.

Thanks

Comment: Show the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is some homework or self learning exercise, usually it is a good idea to use the library functions or the native erlang constructions such as list comprehension:

```
List = [[1], [2], [3], [3,2]],
Result = lists:map(fun(X) -> [length(X)] end, List),
Result = [[length(X)] || X <- List],
```

The usual and straight recursive solution of this problem is

```
lengths_not_tail_recursive([]) -> []; % stop condition
lengths_not_tail_recursive([H|T]) -> [[length(H)]|lengths_not_tail_recursive(T)].
```

This solution is not so bad as long as List is not too big. It is not tail recursive because at each step of the recursion, except the last one, the result of the "local" work need to be combined with the result of the further steps.

To solve this issue, the general solution is to add a new parameter, called accumulator, it will record at each step what was evaluated so far, and the last step will return the final and complete result.

```
lengths_tail_recursive([],Acc) -> lists:reverse(Acc); % stop condition
% the result needs to be reverse due to the way the accumulator is built at each step
lengths_tail_recursive([H|T],Acc) -> lengths_tail_recursive(T,[[length(H)]|Acc]).
```

The difference is that at each recursion step you simply return, without modification, the result of the next step. Generally, this solution uses a second function which role is to hide the need of a second parameter, and initialize this one correctly for the first call

```
lengths(L) -> lengths_tail_recursive(L,[]).
```

*Note: the tail recursive solution uses 2 library functions: length/1 and lists:reverse/1. I invite you to write them in a tail recursive manner*